# i18next bold and list formatter together in react

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

I have an array `const attributes = ['First name', 'Second name', 'Date']`

and I want to render the text Sorry coudn't save **"First name"**, **"Second Name"** and **"Date"**.

As you can see I want to first make each item bold and wrapped with quotes and then use the `Intl.ListFormat`

Im a bit lost on how to do that and could use a little help.

[This is what I have](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-fomtter-b6xcsk?file=/src/App.js:167-295)

```
i18n
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: "en",
    debug: true,

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
      format: function (value, format, lng) {
        if (format === "list") {
          value = value.map((v) => `<bold>${v}</bold>`);
          return new Intl.ListFormat(lng, {
            style: "long",
            type: "conjunction"
          }).format(value);
        }
      }
    },
    resources: {
      en: {
        translation: {
          attr: "A list of {{attr, list}}"
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

```
<Trans
 i18nKey="attr"
 values={{ attr }}
 components={{ bold: <b /> }}
 shouldUnescape={true}
/>
```

```
A list of <bold>First name</bold>, <bold>Second name</bold> and <bold>DOB</bold>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing [interpolation](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation) and [Trans component](https://react.i18next.com/latest/trans-component). This is not possible.

Option 1: **use t function**

```
t('attr', { attr })
```

Option 2: **Trans without list formatting**

```
// resources:
attr: "A list of <1>{{firstName}}</1>, <3>{{lastName}}</3> and <5>{{extra}}</5>"

// Trans:
<Trans
  i18nKey="attr"
  values={{ firstName: attr[0], lastName: attr[1], extra: attr[2] }}
>A list of <b>{attr[0]}</b>, <b>{attr[1]}</b> and <b>{attr[2]}</b></Trans>
```

Comment: Ok mixing is what I needed. So its not possible. 

Answer (score 0):

[I think I got it working.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-fomtter-b6xcsk?file=/src/i18n.js)

```js
i18n
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: "en",
    debug: false,

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
      format: function (value, format, lng) {
        if (format === "emphasizeList") {
          value = value.map((v) => `<strong>″${v}″</strong>`);
          return new Intl.ListFormat(lng, {
            style: "long",
            type: "conjunction"
          }).format(value);
        }
      }
    },
    resources: {
      en: {
        translation: {
          attr: "A list of {{attr, emphasizeList}}"
        }
      }
    }
  });

export default function App() {
  const attr = ["First name", "Second name", "DOB"];

  return <Trans i18nKey="attr" values={{ attr }} />;
}
```